# How to blur everything except fuzzy region of an image in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mask, filter, blur

Suppose I have an image

[image]

and a fuzzy region on it

[image]

Now I wish to "accent" view only in this region. For this purpose I wish to blur everything that is black and to retain sharp everything which is white.

I.e. I wish to create mask which is non uniform.

How to do this in Photoshop?

Comment: There are a few ways to do this; which version of Photoshop are you using?

Answer (score 3):

If you want even more control of the blur, you could use an Iris Blur on a Smart Object:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this will be simple and non-distructive too.

First, right click on the layer in the layer panel and convert it to smart object.

Second, apply the blur you want to the image, (at this stage it will apply to all the image)

Third, the blur you add will create what is called smart filters (because you have a smart object). This smart filter has it's own mask layer - see image below - now you can paint the areas you want in black to mask them and vice versa.

Hope this is clear

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But how to paint inside smart filter? I can't enter it and can't draw anything.

Comment: Sorry for the delay! I am sure you by now figured it out! But for the sake of completing the chain. By double clicking the smart filter you can open its contents, so a smart layer could be a container for other PSD layers.